# React select multiple true- comma separated value display

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

Is it possible to get the display of selected values as comma separated.. instead of the box with cross sign

```
import Select from 'react-select'

<Select
  name=''
  styles={customStyles}
  isClearable
  isMulti
/>
```

Comment: What package are you referring to?

Comment: React-select package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [React-Select](https://react-select.com/home) docs, you can change the styles of the individual selected items.

But, they render as boxes with `x` buttons on them so that the user can choose to de-select any of the selected items.

I would suggest playing with the [React-Select styles](https://react-select.com/styles) like this:

```
<Select
  styles={customStyles}
/>
```

Comment: So there is no way I can display selected values as comma separated?

Comment: No, If you wanted to outside of the component, you could take the options and map them as a comma delimited string: `<div>{yourOptions.map(option => <p>{option}</p>)}</div>`

Answer (score 3):

You can create your own custom `MultiValueContainer` component. To display comma separated options, we can do something like this:

```
render() {
    const components = {
      MultiValueContainer: ({ selectProps, data }) => {
        const values = selectProps.value;
        if (values) {
          return values[values.length - 1].label === data.label
            ? data.label
            : data.label + ", ";
        } else return "";
      }
    };

    return (
      <Select
        value={this.state.value}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        isMulti
        name="colors"
        options={colourOptions}
        className="basic-multi-select"
        classNamePrefix="select"
        components={components}
      />
    );
  }
```

[here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-select-forked-5df1e?file=/example.js:453-1063) is the code sandbox link to see above code in action.